# How to make a redirect in nuxtjs in component method not fetch method?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxtjs , I want to redirect user after he loggedin, redirect() method not working inside my function:

```
 loginUser: function () {
    if (this.isValid) {
      return axios.post(`/user/login`, {email: this.login.email, password: this.login.password})
        .then((res) => {
          let response = res.data
          if (typeof response.token !== 'undefined') {
            setToken(response.token)
            window.location.href = '/'
          }
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e.message)
        })
    }
  }
```

Also access url property not working

```
 loginUser: function () {
    if (this.isValid) {
      return axios.post(`/user/login`, {email: this.login.email, password: this.login.password})
        .then((res) => {
          let response = res.data
          if (typeof response.token !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('loggedin')
            this.props.url.replace('/')
          }
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e.message)
        })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
      loginUser: function () {
    if (this.isValid) {
      return axios.post(`/user/login`, {email: this.login.email, password: this.login.password})
        .then((res) => {
          let response = res.data
          if (typeof response.token !== 'undefined') {
            setToken(response.token)
            console.log('loggedin')
            this.$router.replace('/')
          }
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e.message)
        })
    }
  }
```